# Can't find table when scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have

```py
r = requests.get("https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/custom?year=2021&type=batter&filter=&sort=5&sortDir=desc&min=q&selections=r_total_stolen_base,sprint_speed,&chart=false&x=r_total_stolen_base&y=r_total_stolen_base&r=no&chartType=beeswarm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("tbody")
print(table)
```

it returns `None`, even though there
[is clearly a table tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIbJ2.png)

Comment: Did you check that in ```r.text``` the table also exists?

Comment: yes, i also did lxml instead of html.parser

Comment: why is it named "tbody" ?

Comment: ```soup.find("div", {"id": "sortable_stats"})```?

Comment: im trying to just get the body of the table, not the entire thing

Comment: also `soup.find("div", {"id": "sortable_stats"})` doesn't let me get the `tr` tags :( .

Comment: In the raw HTML the div tag is empty. The table is populated via JavaScript at runtime. You need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which gets the rendered web page from the web browser.

Comment: I think the table does not work if less than 4 columns are specified

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort` URL parameter is set to `5` (the fifth column), but the query selection only returns 3 columns, so no table is displayed when visiting that URL.

Try setting the `?sort=` to `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Example set to 2: https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/custom?year=2021&type=batter&filter=&sort=2&sortDir=desc&min=q&selections=r_total_stolen_base,sprint_speed,&chart=false&x=r_total_stolen_base&y=r_total_stolen_base&r=no&chartType=beeswarm